# Check for Cookie existance, if yes do whatever, if no set a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, setcookie

So what im tryin to do is to check for a cookie existance (for example accepted=yes) If it is not set, it will return nothing and if not, it will execute some script and set the accepted=yes cookie. So that on the next visit the visitor wont see the popup.

```
var cookie = document.cookie;
if (cookie = accepted=yes) {

} else {
    document.cookie = "accepted=yes";
}
```

That is the code i have discovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getCookie and setCookie Functions

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Example

```
var user = getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
  } else {
    user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
    if (user != "" && user != null) {
      setCookie("username", user, 365);
    }
  }
```

Reference: W3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username